# Error : user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)

Tags: haskell

This is a program which is supposed to take input unknown number of text lines and print each line twice but in reverse order 
Sample input :

```
LINE 1
LINE 2
EOF
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT :

```
LINE 2
LINE 2
LINE 1
LINE 1
```

and EOF indicates to stop accepting inputs.

The program compiles (`$ ghc filename.hs`) just fine but at time of input the no parse error occurs (`$ filename: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)`)

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

main = do {
ls <- readlist [];
putStrLn (show (reverse ls));
}
readlist :: [String] -> IO [String]
readlist l = do {
inp <- readLn :: IO String;
if (inp == "EOF") then
return l;
else readlist (inp:l);
}
printOften :: String -> IO ()
printOften str = do {
putStrLn str;
putStrLn str;
}
```

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: This is basically a parse error on the run-time input, which isn't something that the compiler cannot predict or warn you about. You need to share the code and the input that causes the error.

Comment: Do you know what `readLn` does?

Comment: not really ! but i guess it pretty much restricts the input type to String (hear) . Well I am a learner please feel free to tell the exact functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this code I figured out that this code will take a lot of effort to work out so I changed the code a bit,rather then removing the error.

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

main = do {
ls <- readlist [];
printOften ls;
}
readlist :: [String] -> IO [String]
readlist xs = do{
imp <- getLine :: IO String;
if (imp=="EOF")
then return xs
else readlist (imp:xs)
}
printOften :: [String] -> IO ()
printOften [] = return () 
printOften (x:xs) = do {
putStrLn x;
putStrLn x;
printOften xs;
}
```